# String to Double conversion C++

Tags: c++, string, double

I'm trying to convert a string into a double but my double gets cut off at the 3rd decimal point.

My string looks like this: "-122.39381636393"
After it gets converted it looks like this: -122.394

```
void setLongitude(string longitude){
    this->longitude = (double)atof(longitude.c_str());

    cout << "got longitude: " << longitude << endl;
    cout << "setting longitude: " << this->longitude << endl;
}
```

Output example:

```
got longitude: -122.39381636393
setting longitude: -122.394
```

I want it to maintain all the decimal points, any tips?

Comment: `cout` truncates the number of decimals

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would write this code if I were you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "-122.39381636393";
    std::cout.precision(20);
    cout << "setting longitude: " << stod(str) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, you would change things like:

- precision for the printing
- stod rather than low-level operation to get the double back from the string.

You can see it [on ideone running](https://ideone.com/XZHDKM).

Comment: I'm getting a undeclared identifier 'stod'

I have included string and iostream.

`setLatitude(string lat){
    //this->lat = (double)atof(lat.c_str());
    this->lat = stod(lat);
}`

Comment: @jshah: you need to compile with C++11 support, e.g. -std=c++11 in case of gcc and clang.

Comment: I'm using g++ -std=c++11 encounterLocation.cpp and getting the same error.

Comment: My version is: $$ g++ -v
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)

Comment: Whats the best way to go about updating g++? yes, mac

Comment: `clang hpChallenge.cpp 
hpChallenge.cpp:34:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'stod' this->lat = stod(lat);`

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Comment: Try `clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=gnu++11` or just `clang++ -std=gnu++11`.

Comment: You are a beast. clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=gnu++11 worked. Can you please explain?

Comment: @jshah: libstdc++ does not support C++11, only libc++.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably the *printing* that is truncating precision, not the conversion from string to double.

Look at ios_base::precision http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/

e.g. 
`cout.precision(10);
cout << "setting longitude: " << this->longitude << endl;`

Comment: Also you might want to look at boost::lexical_cast for the string to double conversion. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html

Comment: This will not work. The OP needs at least precision 11.

Comment: Thanks! This works with precision 16.

Comment: @jshah: nope, 14, the sign and dot do not count, but your original code is really hack'ish not using existing functionality (strtod/stod). Also, the double cast is superfluous since that is the return value of atof by definition if you look [the man page up](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atof).

Comment: If you are using C++11 stod() may be a good idea, instead of lexical_cast()

Answer (score 2):

The proper C++11 solution is to use `stod` - String TO Double. You probably should use a `try ... catch` around that function as it throws an exception if your string is not a valid number.

However, the code you have, using `atof` is perfectly [assuming no bugs in your particular standard C library] converting to `double` (despite the name being Ascii TO Float, it returns a `double` value), you are just not printing enough digits, use `precision` or `setprecision` to inform `cout` how many digits to use, e.g.

```
cout << "Setting longitude: " << setprecision(15) << this->longitude << endl;
```

You will need to include `<iomanip>` for `setprecision` to work.