# stod conversion some sig figs cut off

Tags: c++, precision

I have 2 string lat long values that I want to convert to double.  When I run stod function some sig figs have been cut off from the original string.

```
double latitude = stod(latstr);
double longitude = stod(longstr);

cout<<"String values:"<<latstr<<","<<longstr<<endl;
cout<<"Double values:"<<latitude<<","<<longitude<<endl;
```

output:

```
String values:21.13134532, -155.325334532
Double values:21.131, -155.325
```

Comment: You sure that's because of `stod()`, and not how they are printed to the screen?

Comment: [std::setprecision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)

Comment: Also, if you use a debugger, it allows you to inspect the variables without the pesky `cout` getting in the way, only the debugger is in the way. See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: https://ideone.com/XEATC9

Comment: @RetiredNinja `std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10)` interesting, thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String to Double conversion C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449986/string-to-double-conversion-c)

Comment: @shaocong that question solves my problem but the title is very misleading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't `stod()`, the problem is how the double is being printed to the screen with `cout`. This can be changed with [std::setprecision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

```
// ...
#include <iomanip>
// ...
double latitude = stod(latstr);
double longitude = stod(longstr);

cout << "String values:" << latstr << "," << longstr << endl;
cout << "Double values:" << std::setprecision(10) << latitude << "," << longitude << endl;
```